# Error 505 during installation from Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I have LG G Pad. I have been trying to update Google Play Services since October. It always fails during installation. Many of my apps are not working such as YouTube, Gmail, etc.

I tried clearing cache, and I also did it with Play Store too. I restarted the tablet after clearing cache and still to no avail can't update Play services. My LG G4 phone has no problem.

What can I do?

Comment: Just for confirmation, is it 505 or -505?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download and install from http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-games/google-play-games-3-7-23-release/google-play-games-3-7-23-2867637-836-android-apk-download/download/

It worked out for me on slimrom for Kindle Fire 5th gen

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 – Restart your Android Phone:**

This is one of the most basic solutions to fix most of the Google Play Store Errors. So, you can try restarting your android phone in order to Fix Error 505 in your android phone. If restarting does not help you fixing the error, then follow below solutions.

**Solution 2 – Clear Cache and Data of Google Play Store, Google Service Framework and Download Manager:**

Since Error 505 can be caused due to cache conflict or data crash, so you can try clearing cache and data of Google Play Store, Google Service Framework and Download Manager. To do the same, follow the below steps.

Go to Settings.
Click on Apps or Application Manager option.
Now, swipe right further to open All tab.
Now, scroll down and look for Google Play Store app. Click on it.
Here, you will see two buttons – 1. Clear Cache and 2. Clear Data. Click on them.
Fix Google Play Store Error 505 in Android
Click on Clear Cache and Clear Data Options
Now, go back and look for Google Service Framework and Download Manager app. Follow the same above step for them too.

**Solution 3 – Reconfigure your Google Account:**

Since Google Play Store Error 505 can also be caused due to Google Account Sync Problem, so try reconfiguring your Google Account again. To do the same, follow below steps.

Go to **Settings.**
Click on Google option under Accounts Section.
Now, click on your Google account and select Remove Account option.
Solution To Fix Google Play Store Error 505 in Android
Remove your Google Account
Now, restart your android phone and reconfigure your Google Account.
Once done, see if it helped you to Fix Android Error 505 in Google Play Store.

**Solution 4 – Factory Reset your Android Phone:**

This is the last option left to Fix Google Play Store Error 505 in Android Phones.